# How to get the Xpath in behat selenium

Tags: php, selenium, xpath, behat

Trying to find Xpath in a page.
here's my code.

```
   $session = $this->getSession();
   $found = $session->getPage()->findAll('xpath', '//meta[@name ="description"]/@content');
   if (is_null($found)) {
      throw new \Exception(sprintf("Could not find meta %s='%s' with '%s'",));
   }
```

giving error

> invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression
>   "//html//meta[@name ="description"]/@content" is: [object Attr]. It
>   should be an element.
>                 (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.103)
>                 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Mac OS X 10.10.5
>   x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using '@content' will return the attribute content, this might not return a valid selector when Behat is translating to xpath.

If you need to specify that attribute you should use it like this:

```
//meta[@name ="description"][@content]
```

Also please note that findAll returns array and not a single element, you can use find to find the first element matching the selector given.

If you need to get a value of an attribute or to get the text you can use methods like getAttribute('attribute_name') or getText().

In your case you can have something like:

```
$found->getAttribute('name');
```

or

```
$found->getText();
```

Comment: Getting new error after that.
invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //html//meta[@name ="description"]@content because of the following error:
        SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//html//meta[@name ="description"]@content' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: copy the exact selector i gave, with @content included in square brackets

Comment: oops that worked, is there a way i can get a value at that xpath?

Comment: first scenario is working, but while  fetching the value echo $elementText = $element->getValue(); it doesn't print anything

Comment: getValue work will work if the element has an attribute named value, else you should use getAttribute and give as parameter a name of an existing attribute. Can you post a html snippet with your element?